# Property of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

While trying to prove that in real number system the sum of two continuous functions is continuous , I found a proof which is clearly understandable but I have encountered a property of real functions which I don't know how to prove.This one underlined with red.

[image]

If someone could help me with that I would really appreciate it . Thank you !

Comment: That's not a property: that's the definition of $f+g$.

Comment: How can I prove it?

Comment: @MathsSurvivor You don't prove definitions.

Comment: Can you give me any link where I can read more about this definition of continuous functions.Thank you!

Comment: It's the definition of the sum of two functions (you sum pointwise)

Comment: @MathsSurvivor it has nothing to do with *continuous* functions! By definition, for any two functions $f,g\colon X\to Y$ (where addition is well-defined on $Y$), $f+g$ is defined as the function $h\colon X\to Y$ such that $h(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. This should be in your textbook or lecture notes, the first time you saw $f+g$ appear.

Comment: Addition of function is usually defined **pointwise**: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise

Comment: @ClementC. I understand it now.Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: @ClementC. I read on Wikipedia about Pointwise Functions and I don't know if I was able to understand it clearly, so I have a question : is it somehow related to isomorphism functions ?

Comment: @MathsSurvivor Not in this context: "pointwise" here just means that the function $f+g$ is defined from $f$ and $g$ on a point-by-point way, i.e. by specifying the value at every $x$ of the domain $(f+g)(x) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$)

Comment: @ClementC. Did you mean $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for all $x$ .Is there any way to check if a function is pointwise (if I can say like this) or not ? I mean like the way we check if it is injective or surjective so is there any way to also check if it is pointwise ? Thank you in return!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics, the qualifier pointwise is used to indicate that a certain property is defined by considering each value ${\displaystyle f(x)}$  of some function ${\displaystyle f.}$  An important class of pointwise concepts are the pointwise operations defined on functions by applying the operations to function values separately for each point in the domain of definition. Important relations can also be defined pointwise.
[image]

This definition of Pointwise operations from Wikipedia helped me to understand what was unclear to me , so I wanted to post it as an answer to my question.

Comment: It might help to think of the following also as pointwise defined operations: addition of ordered $n$-tuples being defined component-wise (because $n$-tuples can be viewed as functions with domain $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}),$ addition of $m \times n$ matrices (because these can be viewed as functions with domain $\{1,2,\ldots,m\} \times \{1,2,\ldots,n\}),$ term-by-term addition of sequences (because sequences can be viewed as functions with domain $\mathbb {N}),$ etc.